Вычесть внутреннюю область из объекта HTML
Как можно сделать так, чтобы из радиальных элементов вычитался (или выглядело так будто вычтена) внутренняя фигура
Сейчас вот так

Хотелось бы чтобы выглядело вот так

оригинальный код https://codepen .io/oliver_merz/pen/zqXZQG


.cssplay-menu {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 568px;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.cssplay-menu>div {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 250px;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 0;
}

.cssplay-menu * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cssplay-menu .holder {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cssplay-menu input {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.cssplay-menu .segment {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -48%;
  margin-top: -48%;
  width: 96%;
  height: 96%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 2.4, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.cssplay-menu .curve-upper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1%;
  top: 1%;
  width: 98%;
  height: 98%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: 0s;
}

.cssplay-menu .curve-lower {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(-140deg) scale(0);
  transition: 0s;
}

.cssplay-menu .curve {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #8b0000;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #008080;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transition: 0.25s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
  transition: 0.25s ease;
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotate(-140deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: rotate(-100deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: rotate(-20deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(5) {
  transform: rotate(20deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(6) {
  transform: rotate(60deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(7) {
  transform: rotate(100deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(8) {
  transform: rotate(140deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(9) {
  transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(1) span {
  background: url(cubic/truck-white.png);
  transform: skewY(-50deg) rotate(0deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(2) span {
  background: url(cubic/location-white.png);
  transform: skewY(-50deg) rotate(-40deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(3) span {
  background: url(cubic/mail-white.png);
  transform: skewY(-50deg) rotate(-80deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(4) span {
  background: url(cubic/pen-white.png);
  transform: skewY(-50deg) rotate(-120deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(5) span {
  background: url(cubic/tag-white.png);
  transform: skewY(-50deg) rotate(-160deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(6) span {
  background: url(cubic/wallet-white.png);
  transform: skewY(-50deg) rotate(-200deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(7) span {
  background: url(cubic/video-white.png);
  transform: skewY(-50deg) rotate(-240deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(8) span {
  background: url(cubic/cup-white.png);
  transform: skewY(-50deg) rotate(-280deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(9) span {
  background: url(cubic/cup-white.png);
  transform: skewY(-50deg) rotate(-320deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .center {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 200;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -20%;
  margin-top: -20%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #8b0000 url(cubic/settings.png) no-repeat center center;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff;
}

.cssplay-menu #toggle:checked+.holder .segment {
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 3, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.cssplay-menu #toggle:checked+.holder .center {
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 3, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.cssplay-menu #toggle:checked+.holder .curve-upper {
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 3, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: 1s ease;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.cssplay-menu #toggle:checked+.holder .curve-lower {
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 3, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: 1s ease;
  transform: rotate(-140deg) scale(1);
}

.cssplay-menu #c1:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(1),
.cssplay-menu #c2:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(2),
.cssplay-menu #c3:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(3),
.cssplay-menu #c4:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(4),
.cssplay-menu #c5:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(5),
.cssplay-menu #c6:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(6),
.cssplay-menu #c7:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(7),
.cssplay-menu #c8:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(8),
.cssplay-menu #c9:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(9) {
  background: #eb8c00;
}

.cssplay-menu #c1:checked~#toggle:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(-140deg)
}

.cssplay-menu #c2:checked~#toggle:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(-100deg)
}

.cssplay-menu #c3:checked~#toggle:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(-60deg)
}

.cssplay-menu #c4:checked~#toggle:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(-20deg)
}

.cssplay-menu #c5:checked~#toggle:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(20deg)
}

.cssplay-menu #c6:checked~#toggle:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(60deg)
}

.cssplay-menu #c7:checked~#toggle:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(100deg)
}

.cssplay-menu #c8:checked~#toggle:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(140deg)
}

.cssplay-menu #c9:checked~#toggle:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(180deg)
}

.cssplay-menu .sub {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  margin-left: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cssplay-menu .sub dl {
  position: absolute;
  top: -190px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 3, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.cssplay-menu .sub dl dt {
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 16px/20px 'Lato', arial, sans-serif;
  color: #8b0000;
}

.cssplay-menu .sub dl dd {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font: normal 15px/20px 'Lato', arial, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
}

.cssplay-menu .sub dl dd a {
  color: #004040;
}

.cssplay-menu #c1:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub dl:nth-of-type(1),
.cssplay-menu #c2:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub dl:nth-of-type(2),
.cssplay-menu #c3:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub dl:nth-of-type(3),
.cssplay-menu #c4:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub dl:nth-of-type(4),
.cssplay-menu #c5:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub dl:nth-of-type(5),
.cssplay-menu #c6:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub dl:nth-of-type(6),
.cssplay-menu #c7:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub dl:nth-of-type(7),
.cssplay-menu #c8:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub dl:nth-of-type(8),
.cssplay-menu #c9:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub dl:nth-of-type(9) {
  top: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 3, 0.5, 0.5) 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease, top 0.5s ease 0.5s;
}

.cssplay-menu #c1:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub,
.cssplay-menu #c2:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub,
.cssplay-menu #c3:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub,
.cssplay-menu #c4:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub,
.cssplay-menu #c5:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub,
.cssplay-menu #c6:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub,
.cssplay-menu #c7:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub,
.cssplay-menu #c8:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub,
.cssplay-menu #c9:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub {
  height: 250px
}
<div class="cssplay-menu">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="c1" name="segment" checked="checked">
    <input type="radio" id="c2" name="segment">
    <input type="radio" id="c3" name="segment">
    <input type="radio" id="c4" name="segment">
    <input type="radio" id="c5" name="segment">
    <input type="radio" id="c6" name="segment">
    <input type="radio" id="c7" name="segment">
    <input type="radio" id="c8" name="segment">
    <input type="radio" id="c9" name="segment">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" checked="checked">
    <div class="holder">
      <div class="segment">
        <label for="c1"><span></span></label>
        <label for="c2"><span></span></label>
        <label for="c3"><span></span></label>
        <label for="c4"><span></span></label>
        <label for="c5"><span></span></label>
        <label for="c6"><span></span></label>
        <label for="c7"><span></span></label>
        <label for="c8"><span></span></label>
        <label for="c9"><span></span></label>
      </div>
      <div class="curve-lower">
        <div class="curve"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="curve-upper"></div>
      <label for="toggle" class="center"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="sub">
      <dl>
        <dt>SUB MENU #1</dt>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #1.1</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #1.2</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #1.3</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #1.4</a></dd>
      </dl>
      <dl>
        <dt>SUB MENU #2</dt>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #2.1</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #2.2</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #2.3</a></dd>
      </dl>
      <dl>
        <dt>SUB MENU #3</dt>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #3.1</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #3.2</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #3.3</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #3.4</a></dd>
      </dl>
      <dl>
        <dt>SUB MENU #4</dt>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #4.1</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #4.2</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #4.3</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #4.4</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #4.5</a></dd>
      </dl>
      <dl>
        <dt>SUB MENU #5</dt>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #5.1</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #5.2</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #5.3</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #5.4</a></dd>
      </dl>
      <dl>
        <dt>SUB MENU #6</dt>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #6.1</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #6.2</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #6.3</a></dd>
      </dl>
      <dl>
        <dt>SUB MENU #7</dt>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #7.1</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #7.2</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #7.3</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #7.4</a></dd>
      </dl>
      <dl>
        <dt>SUB MENU #8</dt>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #8.1</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #8.2</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #8.3</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #8.4</a></dd>
      </dl>
      <dl>
        <dt>SUB MENU #9</dt>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #9.1</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #9.2</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #9.3</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #9.4</a></dd>
      </dl>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Вы же цвет для этого элемента можете поменять, в чем проблема?

Извиняюсь, плохо выразился, мне надо не цвет поменять а геометрию сегментов так чтобы они выглядели так как на нижнем фото. ТО есть в центре нет круга, там пустая область

Для этого его можно сделать прозрачным

Тогда сами сегменты будут просто как дольки круга, а мне надо чтобы они выглядели на нижнем фото. Если делать именно круг прозрачным то этого не будет

Сделайте его белым?

Не, я планирую вставить в свой проект и белый цвет будет перекрывать то, что под ним. Поэтому я и хочу как-то поменять геометрию самих сегментов

самый простой вариант - использовать svg - там можно задать любую форму. Если без svg - можно попробовать использовать clip-path

border + clip-path

относительно недавно попадался подобный челлеж мб что то да приглянётся. p.s. там решения в основном на SVG. а вообще, чего тянуть резину за долгий ящик <tag style='height: 100px; aspect-ratio: 1/1; border-radius: 50%; border: 50px DASHED red'> :3

лол. вспомнился попадавшийся тут закруглённый input[range], всё перерыл и ничего, зато таки нашел готовое SVG колесо. тут у Stranger in the Q (это называется radial menu если верить вики)

Если задача заключается только в прозрачности центрального круга (а также, думаю, это касается и промежутка от сегментов до индикатора), то можно обойтись обычной маской с радиальным градиентом, не прибегая к SVG и clip-path:


body { min-height: 100vh; background: center / cover url('https://umodel.narod.ru/shareweb/image/rainy_night_city.jpg'); }

.cssplay-menu {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 568px;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.cssplay-menu>div {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 250px;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 0;
}

.cssplay-menu * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cssplay-menu .holder {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Маска для прозрачности центрального круга */
  --mask: radial-gradient(#0000 34.65%, #ffff 34.95% 67.5%, #0000 67.8% 69.5%, #ffff 69.7%);
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask); mask: var(--mask);
}

.cssplay-menu input {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.cssplay-menu .segment {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -48%;
  margin-top: -48%;
  width: 96%;
  height: 96%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 2.4, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.cssplay-menu .curve-upper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1%;
  top: 1%;
  width: 98%;
  height: 98%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: 0s;
}

.cssplay-menu .curve-lower {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(-140deg) scale(0);
  transition: 0s;
}

.cssplay-menu .curve {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #8b0000;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #008080;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transition: 0.25s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
  transition: 0.25s ease;
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotate(-140deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: rotate(-100deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: rotate(-20deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(5) {
  transform: rotate(20deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(6) {
  transform: rotate(60deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(7) {
  transform: rotate(100deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(8) {
  transform: rotate(140deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(9) {
  transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(1) span {
  background: url(cubic/truck-white.png);
  transform: skewY(-50deg) rotate(0deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(2) span {
  background: url(cubic/location-white.png);
  transform: skewY(-50deg) rotate(-40deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(3) span {
  background: url(cubic/mail-white.png);
  transform: skewY(-50deg) rotate(-80deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(4) span {
  background: url(cubic/pen-white.png);
  transform: skewY(-50deg) rotate(-120deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(5) span {
  background: url(cubic/tag-white.png);
  transform: skewY(-50deg) rotate(-160deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(6) span {
  background: url(cubic/wallet-white.png);
  transform: skewY(-50deg) rotate(-200deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(7) span {
  background: url(cubic/video-white.png);
  transform: skewY(-50deg) rotate(-240deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(8) span {
  background: url(cubic/cup-white.png);
  transform: skewY(-50deg) rotate(-280deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(9) span {
  background: url(cubic/cup-white.png);
  transform: skewY(-50deg) rotate(-320deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .center {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 200;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -20%;
  margin-top: -20%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #8b0000 url(cubic/settings.png) no-repeat center center;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff;
}

.cssplay-menu #toggle:checked+.holder .segment {
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 3, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.cssplay-menu #toggle:checked+.holder .center {
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 3, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.cssplay-menu #toggle:checked+.holder .curve-upper {
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 3, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: 1s ease;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.cssplay-menu #toggle:checked+.holder .curve-lower {
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 3, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: 1s ease;
  transform: rotate(-140deg) scale(1);
}

.cssplay-menu #c1:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(1),
.cssplay-menu #c2:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(2),
.cssplay-menu #c3:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(3),
.cssplay-menu #c4:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(4),
.cssplay-menu #c5:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(5),
.cssplay-menu #c6:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(6),
.cssplay-menu #c7:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(7),
.cssplay-menu #c8:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(8),
.cssplay-menu #c9:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(9) {
  background: #eb8c00;
}

.cssplay-menu #c1:checked~#toggle:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(-140deg)
}

.cssplay-menu #c2:checked~#toggle:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(-100deg)
}

.cssplay-menu #c3:checked~#toggle:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(-60deg)
}

.cssplay-menu #c4:checked~#toggle:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(-20deg)
}

.cssplay-menu #c5:checked~#toggle:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(20deg)
}

.cssplay-menu #c6:checked~#toggle:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(60deg)
}

.cssplay-menu #c7:checked~#toggle:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(100deg)
}

.cssplay-menu #c8:checked~#toggle:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(140deg)
}

.cssplay-menu #c9:checked~#toggle:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(180deg)
}

.cssplay-menu .sub {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  margin-left: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cssplay-menu .sub dl {
  position: absolute;
  top: -190px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 3, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.cssplay-menu .sub dl dt {
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 16px/20px 'Lato', arial, sans-serif;
  color: #8b0000;
}

.cssplay-menu .sub dl dd {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font: normal 15px/20px 'Lato', arial, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
}

.cssplay-menu .sub dl dd a {
  color: #004040;
}

.cssplay-menu #c1:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub dl:nth-of-type(1),
.cssplay-menu #c2:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub dl:nth-of-type(2),
.cssplay-menu #c3:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub dl:nth-of-type(3),
.cssplay-menu #c4:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub dl:nth-of-type(4),
.cssplay-menu #c5:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub dl:nth-of-type(5),
.cssplay-menu #c6:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub dl:nth-of-type(6),
.cssplay-menu #c7:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub dl:nth-of-type(7),
.cssplay-menu #c8:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub dl:nth-of-type(8),
.cssplay-menu #c9:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub dl:nth-of-type(9) {
  top: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 3, 0.5, 0.5) 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease, top 0.5s ease 0.5s;
}

.cssplay-menu #c1:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub,
.cssplay-menu #c2:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub,
.cssplay-menu #c3:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub,
.cssplay-menu #c4:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub,
.cssplay-menu #c5:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub,
.cssplay-menu #c6:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub,
.cssplay-menu #c7:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub,
.cssplay-menu #c8:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub,
.cssplay-menu #c9:checked~#toggle:checked~.sub {
  height: 250px
}
<div class="cssplay-menu">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="c1" name="segment" checked="checked">
    <input type="radio" id="c2" name="segment">
    <input type="radio" id="c3" name="segment">
    <input type="radio" id="c4" name="segment">
    <input type="radio" id="c5" name="segment">
    <input type="radio" id="c6" name="segment">
    <input type="radio" id="c7" name="segment">
    <input type="radio" id="c8" name="segment">
    <input type="radio" id="c9" name="segment">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" checked="checked">
    <div class="holder">
      <div class="segment">
        <label for="c1"><span></span></label>
        <label for="c2"><span></span></label>
        <label for="c3"><span></span></label>
        <label for="c4"><span></span></label>
        <label for="c5"><span></span></label>
        <label for="c6"><span></span></label>
        <label for="c7"><span></span></label>
        <label for="c8"><span></span></label>
        <label for="c9"><span></span></label>
      </div>
      <div class="curve-lower">
        <div class="curve"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="curve-upper"></div>
      <label for="toggle" class="center"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="sub">
      <dl>
        <dt>SUB MENU #1</dt>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #1.1</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #1.2</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #1.3</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #1.4</a></dd>
      </dl>
      <dl>
        <dt>SUB MENU #2</dt>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #2.1</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #2.2</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #2.3</a></dd>
      </dl>
      <dl>
        <dt>SUB MENU #3</dt>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #3.1</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #3.2</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #3.3</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #3.4</a></dd>
      </dl>
      <dl>
        <dt>SUB MENU #4</dt>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #4.1</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #4.2</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #4.3</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #4.4</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #4.5</a></dd>
      </dl>
      <dl>
        <dt>SUB MENU #5</dt>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #5.1</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #5.2</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #5.3</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #5.4</a></dd>
      </dl>
      <dl>
        <dt>SUB MENU #6</dt>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #6.1</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #6.2</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #6.3</a></dd>
      </dl>
      <dl>
        <dt>SUB MENU #7</dt>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #7.1</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #7.2</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #7.3</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #7.4</a></dd>
      </dl>
      <dl>
        <dt>SUB MENU #8</dt>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #8.1</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #8.2</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #8.3</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #8.4</a></dd>
      </dl>
      <dl>
        <dt>SUB MENU #9</dt>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #9.1</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #9.2</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #9.3</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#url">Item #9.4</a></dd>
      </dl>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



